# NVD3 lineChart Conditional Area Color Based On Y Axis

Tags: javascript, node.js, colors, nvd3.js

I'm trying to have positive Y values fill with blue and negatives with red. Here is what my graph looks like: [Image of Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na1gF.png).

I'm currently adding the color to my dataset in app.js:

```
if(displayData["VARIANCE"] >= 0){
    ctvar.push({
        x: Date.now(), y: displayData["VARIANCE"], color:"#0000ff"
    });
}else{
    ctvar.push({
        x: Date.now(), y: displayData["VARIANCE"], color:"#ff0000"
    });
}
```

The dataset is passed to my jade template file as `ctvv` where I set all the graph settings in js:

```
function myData() {
return [
    {
        key: "Cycle time Variance",
        values: ctvv,
        area: true
    }
];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Time").tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
  });
chart.lines.scatter.xScale(d3.time.scale());
chart.yAxis.axisLabel("Seconds").tickFormat(d3.format("d")).ticks(5);
chart.yDomain([-60,60]);
d3.select("svg").datum(myData()).transition().duration(0).call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(
        function() {
            chart.update();
        }
    );
return chart;
});
```

I've tried setting the chart colors using the ctvv and also a plain array of colors.